# Recursive function of generic type

Tags: c#, class, generics, recursion, types

I'm trying to write a recursive function function that takes a class as argument and check all its member to make sure that all members are either type of field or nested type. the function should call itself for taking the nested type members as argument. This is where I fail:

```
    private void Validate<C>() where C : class
    {
        MemberInfo[] x = typeof(C).GetMembers();
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            if (x[i].MemberType != MemberTypes.Field && x[i].MemberType != MemberTypes.NestedType)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Class members must be of type Field or NestedType"));
            }
//here I have problem sending 'a' as argument to the validate function 
      x.Where(a => a.MemberType == MemberTypes.NestedType).ToList().ForEach(a => Validate<typeof(a)>());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to use reflection.

Comment: @SLaks could you please show me how?

Comment: Minor unrelated bug: The condition should contain an `&&`, not an `||`; otherwise, it will always be trivially satisfied: `x[i].MemberType != MemberTypes.Field && x[i].MemberType != MemberTypes.NestedType`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easier solution would be to define a private method overload that accepts a `Type` parameter:

```
private void Validate<C>() where C : class
{
    Validate(typeof(C));
} 

private void Validate(Type type)
{
    MemberInfo[] x = type.GetMembers();
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        if (x[i].MemberType != MemberTypes.Field && x[i].MemberType != MemberTypes.NestedType)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Class members must be of type Field or NestedType"));
        }

        foreach (var n in x.GetNestedTypes())
            Validate(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Greaaaaat, thanks a lot. by the way it should be `n.GetType()` ;)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: You're right to point out that I was erroneously passing a `MemberInfo` to `Validate`. However, I don't think that calling `MemberInfo.GetType` is correct, since it returns the type information for `RuntimeType`. I would suggest using [`GetNestedTypes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getnestedtypes(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, as shown in the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Reflection to invoke the method with the correct type parameter:

```
typeof(YourClass)
    .GetMethod(nameof(Validate))
    .MakeGenericMethod(a.GetType())
    .Validate()
```

Comment: well in this case what should I replace `YourClass` with in my coe? this is my problem

Comment: The class that contains your method.